# Keyboard layout changed but I don't know why

Tags: help, keyboard-layout

Sometimes, when I type quickly I do something that change the keyboard layout: the key that would produce `<` now produces `|`. Problem is that I don't know how I cause that and how to undo that! If I close and open again Emacs everything is fine, but I would like to avoid it. Any clue?

Comment: `M-x command-history` to check what you might have activated by mistake

Comment: By default you can toggle an input method by typing `C-\​` That's probably what you've typed by accident. You should be able to see that command in lossage `F1 l`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `C-h l` (command `view-lossage`) to see the last few key sequences (including mouse actions) that you used, plus their associated commands.

`C-h k C-h l` tells you:

> **`view-lossage`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `help.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-h l`, `f1 l`, `help l`, `menu-bar help-menu whereami
>   view-lossage`.
>
> `(view-lossage)`
>
> Display last few input keystrokes and the commands run.
>
> For convenience this uses the same format as
>   `edit-last-kbd-macro`.
>
> To record all your input, use `open-dribble-file`.

That last statement tells you how to record more than just the last few keystrokes.  `C-h f open-dribble-file` (or clicking the linked name in the previous help display) tells you:

> **`open-dribble-file`** is an interactive built-in function in `C source
>   code`.
>
> `(open-dribble-file FILE)`
>
> Start writing all keyboard characters to a dribble file called FILE.
>
> If `FILE` is `nil`, close any open dribble file.
>   The file will be closed when Emacs exits.
>
> Be aware that this records **ALL** characters you type!
>   This may include sensitive information such as passwords.